# The implementation of HOG Descriptor

Tags: java, algorithm, opencv, image-processing, computer-vision

I am trying to implement the Hog Descriptor using java without using Hog descriptor which is implemented in opencv, but I have the following questions:

1. Are HOG Detector and HOG Descriptor the same?
2. After we extract interest points or key points from an image from what do we extract HOG descriptor? Form the whole image or from the interest points / key points which we detected before from image.
3. When we compute the gradient do we divide the image into blocks before or after we compute the image gradient?

Regards 
Thanks in advance

Comment: 1. the detector is an svm pre-trained on descriptors. descriptors are a collection of hog-features(gradients)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well,

1. I haven't used HoG specifically but judging from other descriptors, usually they are not the same. The actual feature is the descriptor while the detector as you can guess it is used to detect (to locate) the feature.
2. There is no point in finding interesting points and then extract features from the whole image. (Again) I don't know how HoG exactly work but usually either you extract features from the whole image or first detect interesting points and then extract from them. (Some features cannot be extracted from the whole image though).
3. Judging from the answers in [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Histogram_of_oriented_gradients) the usual approach involves the calculation of the local features and then use the blocks to `group the cells together into larger, spatially connected blocks` to improve illumination etc robustness, so first you calculate HoG on cell level and then use the block to groug them together.

Comment: Thank you  Eypros for the quick response and editing !
 This is very helpful!

Comment: If you find it helpful (and this include any other answer you get) consider upvoting the answer and/or also accepting. This helps also others distinguish useful answers

Comment: thanks ,but i need more clear answers from any one who used Hog Descriptor :)

Comment: Well it's not in my favor to say so but you don't have to accept an answer simply because it's useful. Read this http://stackoverflow.com/tour to understand when you should accept an answer. If you find it useful you can just upvote it. And of course you can take it both decisions back if you change your mind.